# How does hashmap instantiation work under the hood?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

I was taught that a hashmaps are O(1) (ignoring collisions). This was explained to me as follows:

A range in memory is reserved for the hashmap. A key is hashed to a seemingly random address in this range. We store the key-value pair at that address. The possibility that multiple keys can hash to the same address is solved either by rehashing the hash every time such a collision occurs or by having each utilized address store a pointer to a linked list of everything hashed to that address.

A key can later be hashed to check whether a matching key-value pair is found (reutilizing the same collision resolution used during storage if necessary). If the key is found, the value is returned.

But if a range of memory is assigned to a hashmap, there is a chance that the bits previously there would mimic a key-value pair being present. So I think the hashmap's memory range must be sanitized on instantiation (or even earlier...?). Since that range cannot be significantly smaller than the number of items to be stored, wouldn't that sanitation be O(n)? Does modern hardware solve this by having any instruction to fill a range of memory with a repeated value? If so, did the advent of this instruction make hashmaps viable? Otherwise, I do not understand how this works. Sure, this O(n) would be a one-time event on instantiation. But other storage methods should be able to never do anything slower than O(log(n)). Please help me, what am I missing?

Comment: Your big-O notation is... awful. This are not `O(n)=1`, they're `O(1)`. Or `O(log n)` or `O(n)`, etc.

Comment: Aside from that, you're going off in the *completely* wrong direction. There's no magic bit pattern involved (unless you count `NULL`, and zeroing memory has been an easily done thing for a long time; the OS *always* does it before handing you new memory blocks on all but the simplest embedded systems). Regardless, the individual insert/lookup/delete operations are `O(1)` because you *don't* need to rezero the whole table just to insert one value. You don't need someone to answer your question, you need to read [the Wikipedia article on hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: Good point @ShadowRanger, edited to fix.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I would count NULL as a "magic bit pattern". If I malloc in C, the memory allocated isn't automatically all set to NULL. You are right to say the insert/lookup/delete are still O(1), but that doesn't actually answer the question about the performance of instantiation, nor does the Wikipedia article you linked as far as I can tell. I think you are tacitly saying that if I use a hashmap from a library, it is using something like C's memset... Are you saying that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical HashMap implementation will allocate a small table when it's constructed.  Then when the number of items exceeds some constant factor of the table size, it will allocate a table twice as big and move all the keys over to the new one.

This leads to an amortized O(1) insertion time, but an actual worst case insertion of O(n) when the table needs to be allocated.  Dealing with collisions degrades that "amortized" O(1) time to "expected" O(1) time.

It's *possible*, however, to move the keys over to the reallocated table incrementally, spreading out that cost so that it really is O(1) per operation. This is rarely done, though, because it doesn't guarantee O(1) time -- there's that collision problem again, and there is no guarantee that you can even allocate memory in constant time.

---

That answers your question about hash maps, but your original line of thinking around the cost of initialization also does not *theoretically* apply.  See this answer: [Initializing an Array in the Context of Studying Data Structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641224/initializing-an-array-in-the-context-of-studying-data-structures/63649361#63649361)

Comment: Thanks!, the second part of your answer is exactly what I'm trying to understand. In the answer you linked, how would you be able to assume that what looks like a counter in B and an index in C aren't random garbage that happen to look like a counter and an index (without initializing the values in B and C)?

Comment: You know that all C[i] are valid for i < N., so you know when it's not garbage.  Given that C[B[i]] is not garbage, C[B[i]]==i proves that B[i] is not garbage.  If you want to ask more questions about that answer, you should do it over there.

Comment: I just understood your post in the other thread. Thanks, makes sense! In your other post, you said that isn't how it is usually done in practice. Does this mean in practice a single array is initialized to contain repeat values of something like NULL?

Comment: yes.  Allocation isn't guaranteed to be constant time, anyway, so normally we just initialize the array.