# Better big O worse real time execution

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, big-o

So I'm following a algorithms course and it asked to implement the following function:

> Write a function called findLongestSubstring, which accepts a string and returns the length of the longest substring with all distinct characters.
>
> findLongestSubstring('') // 0
>
> findLongestSubstring('bbbbbb') // 1
>
> findLongestSubstring('longestsubstring') // 8

And said it has to have a time complexity of o(n).
So I could not come up with a o(n) solution, but a supposed (n^2)... my naive solution:

```js
function findLongestSubstring(str: string): number {
  const array = str.split("");
  let maxLength = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const letterArray = [array[i]];

    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (letterArray.find(e => e === array[j])) {
        if (letterArray.length > maxLength) maxLength = letterArray.length;
        break;
      } else {
        letterArray.push(array[j])
        if (j === array.length - 1) {
          if (letterArray.length > maxLength) maxLength = letterArray.length;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

  }

  return maxLength;
}
```

Then I went to check his solution:

```js
function findLongestSubstring(str: string) {

  let longest = 0;
  let seen = {};
  let start = 0;
 
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let char = str[i];
    if (seen[char]) {
      start = Math.max(start, seen[char]);
    }
    // index - beginning of substring + 1 (to include current in count)
    longest = Math.max(longest, i - start + 1);
    // store the index of the next char so as to not double count
    seen[char] = i + 1;
  }
  return longest;
}
```

So I do agree that my solution which has a nested for loop appears to be O(n2) and his solution o(n). But when I tested both algorithms with a really big string to my surprise my algorithm was acctually faster and i have NO idea why... can someone enlight me?
The way Im testing:

```js
  test("really big string to test bigO", () => {
    const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    const randomLettersArray = Array.from({ length: 100000000 }, () => alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)]);
    const randomBigString = randomLettersArray.join("")


    const start = Date.now();

    findLongestSubstring(randomBigString);

    const end = Date.now();
    console.log(`Execution time: ${end - start} ms`);
  })
```

Comment: What is `alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)]` intended to do? *e*: I see what it does in the `Array.from()` callback, maybe that's just vestigial code.

Comment: Time complexity describes how the running time changes as the length of the input grows. So O(n^2) just means that if you double the length of the input, the running time is multiplied by 4. But that doesn't mean that an O(n) algorithm is faster than O(n^2), because big-O ignores coefficients that represent the efficiency of each step in the process.

Comment: I suspect that the nested-loop solution will be pretty efficient on some inputs, and less so on others. On text input that might have more "real" sequences of characters, or on non-text structured content, it could be much slower. It's all about how often that inner loop gets up to a higher value of `j`.

Comment: You could try a test where you build a long string differently. Pick random lengths less than the length of `alphabet`, and then use that to build substrings and glue them together. That will ensure you get more longer target substrings to check.

Comment: Running your little test on my machine shows your nested loop being significantly slower than the other (and also to slow down increasingly as expected with n^2). In these cases question the micro-testing before anything else. **Yours**: `1000 -> 6ms`, `10_000 -> 9ms`, `100_000 -> 38ms`. **Theirs**: `1000 -> 0ms`, `10_000 -> 4ms`, `100_000 -> 8ms`

Comment: As an analogy, why should an accelerating fast moving object be accelerating more rapidly than a slow moving accelerating object? You are dealing with rates and how those rates change. The O measure is an indication of how rates change and say nothing about the rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nested loop solution looks like it could take O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, but it's actually limited by the longest possible valid substring, and that is limited by the *size of the alphabet*.

Your test uses a small alphabet -- only 26 characters.  Your inner loop has a maximum of 26 iterations in this case, and that just might be faster than the other algorithm in some environments.

If you were to use a much larger alphabet -- say 10000 characters or so, then your algorithm would be much slower, but the other one would not slow down much at all.

Comment: Good observation. I have a solution that works in time O(n), with extra space m bits where m is the size of the alphabet. The cost of initializing the m bits, in theory O(m),  can be ignored, because the algorithm restores them to their initial values upon termination.

Comment: The cost of initializing an array can always be ignored: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641224/initializing-an-array-in-the-context-of-studying-data-structures/63649361#63649361

Comment: This is not true if the algorithm is to be used repeatedly. In this case, explicit re-initialization may be necessary.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Just to clarify, whether the max were 26 iterations or 10000 iterations, the inner loop has a max constant limit unrelated to N.  You're strongly implying that despite surface appearances, the OP's solution is O(N).

Comment: @phatfingers You are implying it more strongly than I am.  I don't think that stating either "O(N)" or "O(N^2)" is an effective way to communicate the worst case performance of the OP's algorithm.  I would say O(N |S|), where |S| is the alphabet size.

Answer (score 0):

Let us condider all longest subtrings (meeting the distinctness condition) that end at the successive positions:

```
l -> l
lo -> lo
lon -> lon
long -> long
longe -> longe
longes -> longes
longest -> longest
longests -> ts
longestsu -> tsu
longestsub -> tsub
longestsubs -> ubs
longestsubst -> ubst
longestsubstr -> usbtr
longestsubstri -> ubstri
longestsubstrin -> ubstrin
longestsubstring -> ubstring
```

You will notice that the index of the first character never descreases. Every time one appends a new character, the starting index either does not change, or it moves past the position of the same character in the substring.

So the following loop could do:

```
the substring is empty
for all ending positions in the string:
  append the new character to the substring
  move the starting position past the same character in the substring, if any
```

But we are not done yet: if the new character is found in the substring, the starting cursor will stop there; but if it is not found, we need to traverse the whole substring for nothing, and this can make the complexity quadratic.

So we need an extra device to tell us if the substring contains the new character *without traversing the substring*. As the alphabet has a finite size, we can do with an array of booleans which will act as counters. Initially all booleans are zero; when a character enters/exits the substring, its entry in the array is set/reset.

Hence the whole search can be performed in linear time. Of course the solution is the length of the longest string found during this process.

```
all booleans are initially reset
the substring is empty
for all ending positions in the string:
  append the new character to the substring
  if the boolean for this character is set:
     move the starting position past the same character in the substring,
       while resetting the booleans of all characters met
  set the boolean for this character
  update the longest length so far
```

Comment: Nice approach, but not what the OP is asking for help with.