# Unabale to find the best case time complexity of priority queue Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, priority-queue, dijkstra

I found the introduction of dijkstra algorithm in geeksforgeeks:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/

[time complexity of dijkstra algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwKRW.png)

Pseudocode:

```
function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
    // Initialize distances to all nodes as infinity, except for the source node.
    distances = map infinity to all nodes
    distances = 0

    // Initialize an empty set of visited nodes and a priority queue to keep track of the nodes to visit.
    visited = empty set
    queue = new PriorityQueue()
    queue.enqueue(source, 0)

    // Loop until all nodes have been visited.
    while queue is not empty:
        // Dequeue the node with the smallest distance from the priority queue.
        current = queue.dequeue()

        // If the node has already been visited, skip it.
        if current in visited:
            continue

        // Mark the node as visited.
        visited.add(current)

        // Check all neighboring nodes to see if their distances need to be updated.
        for neighbor in Graph.neighbors(current):
            // Calculate the tentative distance to the neighbor through the current node.
            tentative_distance = distances[current] + Graph.distance(current, neighbor)
            // If the tentative distance is smaller than the current distance to the neighbor, update the distance.
            if tentative_distance < distances[neighbor]:
                distances[neighbor] = tentative_distance

                // Enqueue the neighbor with its new distance to be considered for visitation in the future.
                queue.enqueue(neighbor, distances[neighbor])

    // Return the calculated distances from the source to all other nodes in the graph.
    return distances
```

It indicates that the worst case time complexity is O((V + E) log V), what is the time complexity of best case scenario?

I search through the internet and found nothing about the time complexity for best case

Comment: The best case is O(1), which happens, for example, when the target is the source's nearest neighbor.  This is a completely useless fact.

Comment: Oh, you don't have a target.  In that case the best case is O(1), which happens, for example, then the source is disconnected from the rest of the graph.  Also useless.

Comment: @MattTimmermans there is distances = map infinity to all nodes O(N), Queue operation O(log n), why it is O(1) if we should take the dominant term

Comment: Priority queues are an abstract data type with several possible implementations (sorted or unsorted linked list, binary heap, skew heap, binary search tree, splay tree,…). Performance per operation type depends on the specific implementation used.

Comment: @pjs Im using heapq in Python, how can I get the best case time complexity?

Comment: Your question says “pseudocode”, it is not tagged `python`. I’m not a python user, I’d recommend reading `heapq` documentation.

Comment: @codeNewBie You can initialize distances in constant time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641224/initializing-an-array-in-the-context-of-studying-data-structures/63649361#63649361  Enqueue is also O(1) when the queue is empty.

Comment: Best case is O(N), but only because of the initialisation of `distances` as it is done in this pseudocode. A priority queue based algorithm actually doesn't need `distances`. It can pair the calculated distances with the nodes on the priority queue. And then best case is O(1).

Comment: @trincot do we need to consider the main loop "while queue is not empty" O(V) and "for neighbor in Graph.neighbors(current)" O(E)?

Comment: The empty check is O(1). And assuming an adjacency list data structure, the lookup for neighbors of a given node is O(k) , where k is the number of neighbors. In the best case there are none, making it O(1). There is only one iteration of the outer loop in the best case, so it's all O(1) then.

Comment: @trincot so the best-case adjacency list only contains one node without any neighbours? I thought it was a graph that the source node directly connects to other node

Comment: A graph does not necessarily have to have just [one component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)). It all depends on what the constraints are that your specific "problem" has, but in general a graph does not *require* that all nodes can be reached from any other node.

Comment: As @MattTimmermans pointed out, best case analysis is generally not helpful. Consider [bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort), which has an expected run time of (n * n!) but a best case run time of Omega(n) if the data are pre-sorted or you get really really lucky on the first iteration. To put that in perspective, if you can do one iteration per nanosecond and want to sort 100 items, the best case is well under a millisecond but for data that aren't pre-sorted you can expect to wait 2.9*10^143 years to get an answer (and it can take much longer than that sometimes).